# How do I unset the :active state on an element in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an element which, when you click on it, shows an inner element sliding up using CSS transitions. I do this by changing the inner element's height in CSS' `:active` on the parent node. I cannot figure out how to unset this afterwards. None of the following work:

```
/* NONE OF THESE WORK */
//Attempt 1
document.activeElement = null;

//Attempt 2
document.activeElement.blur();

//Attempt 3
document.body.focus();

//Attempt 4
document.body.click();

//Attempt 5
myElement.blur();
```

Is there a way to make it not active?

Comment: Do you want the inner element to hide again?

Comment: @nnnnnn yes. I want it to go back to the previous state.

Comment: `:active` is unset by default on `mouseup`:https://jsfiddle.net/nr5nd9p2/1/

Comment: @wscourge Not on mobile

Comment: @DonRhummy, for some reason people did not understand @wscourge's or my answer.  You can easily solve this by defining the `:active` state in a class, and then `classList.remove()` that class to return to your previous state.

Comment: Have you set a default style for the inner element so that it knows what explicit size to return to?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove CSS `:active` pseudoclass using `element.classList.remove("hasactive");`

```js
var inner = document.getElementById("inner");

inner.addEventListener("transitionend", function(evt){
 this.parentNode.classList.remove("hasactive");
})
```

```css
#outer:active #inner {
  height: 200px;
  
}
#inner { 
  background: red; 
  height: 0;
  transition: height 1s linear;
  -webkit-transition: height 1s linear;
}
#outer {
  height: 30px;
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The downvoters just don't understand.  This is how to do it.  However, why do you need `#inner` and `#outer` elements?

Comment: I tried to provide an example referring to the question: *I have an element which, when you click on it, shows an inner element*

Comment: Am I just missing something here or is no `.hasactive` CSS rule being applied? Please explain.